# How to get Eclipse to recognize my LG Phoenix phone so I can debug my android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to test my android app (android 2.3.3) via my LG Phoenix phone. However, I cannot get Eclipse to recognize my device on the debug config menu.  My phone is recognized by my computer when I connect via the usb cable. I can access my phone via windows but not Eclipse. Also, the LG driver has been recently updated when I updated to android 2.3.4.

The reason I am using my phone to debug is b.c the emulator keeps crashing/failing to install my app. I am running Windows Vista 32bit. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your phone to Debug mode when USB is connected?

Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging Checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#components):

> **USB Driver for Windows** (Windows only) — Contains driver files that you can install on your Windows computer, so that you can run and debug your applications on an actual device. You do not need the USB driver unless you plan to debug your application on an actual Android-powered device. If you develop on Mac OS X or Linux, you do not need a special driver to debug your application on an Android-powered device. See [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for more information about developing on a real device.

Make sure you have installed the USB driver for Windows.